# Can't change port of composer-rest-server

Tags: rest, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to change the port of the composer-rest-server and I'm using the `-p` flag as the help says

However the terminal says that I am missing a parameter

**Input**:

```
composer-rest-server -p 8919
```

**Output**:

```
Missing parameter. Please run composer-rest-server -h to see usage details
```

And when I type the `-h` flag:

```
-p, --port                   The port to serve the REST API on  [number]
```

So, how do I run the `composer-rest-server` on a different port from 3000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use full format for running a business network in different port using this:

```
composer-rest-server -c admin@sample-network -p 8919
```

or you can add more parameter like authentication, multiple user support etc.

```
composer-rest-server -c admin@sample-network -p 8919 -a false -m true
```

Know all parameters meaning by using this command.

```
 composer-rest-server --help
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify business network card name (required)

```
composer-rest-server -c businessNetworkCardName -p portNumber
```

For help

```
composer-rest-server -h
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> `composer-rest-server -P portNumber`

you are using -p which is use for connection profile name and
-P use for port number

Comment: composer-rest-server -c businessNetworkName -p portName